# Looking for an API to employ the wonderful powers of the GPU from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm looking for a nice API to use for implementing algorithms on the GPU. I would prefer something relevantly simple and flexible. I'm not looking for the most hardcore performance, but for something I can play around with. Also I would really prefer something that works both on Nvidia and ATI cards...

---

Good recommendation, especially based on experience might be rewarded with a bounty.

---

Currently the algorithms we are discussing are image processing, i.e. relevantly simple manipulations over very large matrices...

for me I would love to be able to just take PLINQ expressions to the GPU, And also have an API like System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel , that would execute stuff on the GPU...

We're mostly in the initial exploring phase here...

And again working cross platform is pretty much a requirement...

Comment: [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164112.aspx)?

Comment: Take a look at TidePowerD's "GPU.Net"::  https://msmvps.com/blogs/brunoboucard/archive/2011/09/28/introduction-to-gpu-programming-part-1.aspx  http://www.tidepowerd.com/

Comment: @UweKeim I'm looking for a way to get very high performance for a lot of simple parallel computations. DX isn't really the way to go :-P

Comment: There's a bit of a bootstrapping problem here.  Somebody is first going to have to write a CLR that runs on a GPU.  Don't hold your breath for that.

Comment: We ended up going with C++ AMP... so no C#...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several options (sometimes with a difference regarding ATI versus nVidia though):

- [Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/)
- [GPU.NET](http://www.tidepowerd.com/)
- [Brahma](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/)
- [CUDAfy.NET](http://www.hybriddsp.com/Products/CUDAfyNET.aspx) (for a nice article see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289551/High-Performance-Queries-GPU-vs-PLINQ-vs-LINQ))
- [GLinq](http://blog.neteril.org/2010/06/18/tying-mono-and-opencl/)
- [OpenCL.NET](http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/OpenCL.NET/Default.aspx)
- [Conflux](http://code.google.com/p/conflux/)
- [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/)
- [VS 2011 Preview AMP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/03/c-amp-open-spec-published.aspx) - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/21/10214538.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/12/10236375.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/09/19/vs-11-developer-preview-gotchas-with-c-amp.aspx) too

As per comments:

From the question it is hard to give any recommendation since some relevant aspects like are the algorithms easily expressed via LINQ ? How deep should .NET integration go ? etc. are basically not clear to me from the question... the above is just a list of currently available technologies to use GPUs for computational work via .NET .

IF a recommendation is needed please give more details on the type development/projects you want to implement...

Comment: Which one would you recommend in regards to OP's requests: simplicity and HW-independence?

Comment: @NikolaAnusev this is hard to answer because there are not much details about what the OP want to do... if the algorithms he want to implement are easily expressed with LINQ then either Brahma or GLinq, if best .NET integration is wanted then GPU.NET (although it is nVidia-only in its current state) etc. Basically without any further details I can only speculate...

Comment: @AK_ there is currently nothing on the market in production quality to fullfill all your requirements... if you can wait for VS 2011 / AMP to come out in production quality you might get most of what you want... otherwise you will need to sacrifice some part of the requirements IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other projects mentioned in other answers, I think it's worth to mention [Cloo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/) project, which is opensource object-oriented .NET wrapper of OpenCL.